# Is there a way to insert a new value into an array with coodinates? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a dataset (called var) which is made up of a list of wind speed values, set at specified longitude, latitude and depth coordinates but changing with time.

It looks like this: [image: dataset]

The dataset skips over one of the time variables (the time is months of the year but written as hours since 01/01/1900 and February 2010 is missing) so I have calculated an estimated value for the wind speed on February 2010 called feb_av. I now want to insert this into the data array at the point between Jan 2010 and March 2010 (currently indexes 32 and 33), I can easily insert the variable using:

```py
ds2_c = np.insert(var, 33, feb_av, axis=None)
```

However this just makes the wind speed set a length of 152 and keeps the time set a length of 151, how do I add in the time variable as well? (The time variable to insert is 964992.)

Comment: Is the use of `xarray` significant?  If `var` is `xarray`, what is the type of `ds2_c`?

Comment: So ds2_c is var including the additional value for february. Just to keep them separate really. var is an xarray and i want ds2_c to be the same xarray but including additional data for february 10 (wind speed value calculated (feb_av) and the time index)

Comment: Why are you using the numpy insert to do this?  Is ds2_c still an xarray with time indices?  or just a ndarray?

Comment: I dont know if the numpy insert is the right method, its the only thing i could find which could insert a value into the xarray. ds2_c comes out as an xarray with time indices except that the variable (wind speed) is now 152 values long whereas the time coordinate is still only 151 values long

Comment: I should mention I am quite new to coding so what i have done is probably wrong!